# How do you refresh your ViewModel when navigating back using MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-7, light

When navigating back using the back button on the phone how can I refresh my ViewModel?

I'm using the back button on the phone but I believe its the same as calling NavigationService.GoBack(), which navigates to the previous page on the stack but the constructor is not called in my View or ViewModel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hook in a base Page class the OnNavigatingTo event and call a method on your ViewModel. I don't have a VS with me but a pseudo-code would be:

in MyBasePAge : Page

```
public void OnNavigatingTo(object sender, eventargs e)
{
   var vm = this.DataContext as BaseViewModel;
   if(vm != null)
   {
      vm.Initialize();
   }
 }
```

you can do the same before leaving the page:

```
public void OnNavigatingFrom(object sender, eventargs e)
{
   var vm = this.DataContext as BaseViewModel;
   if(vm != null)
   {
      vm.Save();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I had to add a _Loaded flag in there to keep it from calling Initialize on the initial page load.  Seems to work, thanks.  Maybe i should call it Refresh() instead of Initialize()

Comment: How can your PhoneApplicationPages inherit from the base page?